# where we use "what" and where we use "which"?

Tags: word-choice, grammar

Sometimes, I get confused when I want to ask a question,so I need some clarification.

Comment: This question may be asked on [ell.se] if it is not GR there.

Comment: The answer that is marked as duplicate is only about _which_ and _what_ in information questions, not about _which_ and _what_ in relative clauses, free relatives, or embedded question clauses.